# Is the Alt+Tab & Menu Bar interraction broken?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

That started happening about a week ago. Previously, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> worked as expected, and would keep the focus where it was left off.

For example, right now, I have the text box highlighted in Skype. I <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> away to this browser, and then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> back into Skype. (I haven't used the cursor or anything, just alt tabbing) The menu bar is now selected in Skype, which previously was not the case.

I know that the <kbd>alt</kbd> button focuses the menu bar, but that hasn't been the case with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. This also happens with the Spotify app, and maybe other things I haven't tested as well. However, this is also inconsistent. Sometimes it selects the menu bar and sometimes it works as usual.